# Высоты внешнего и внутреннего div'а

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите сделать у внешнего и внутреннего `div`'ов ровные высоты

```css
.paper {
  padding: 0;
  height: 350px
}

.paper-inner {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #747474;
  padding: 30px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="paper">
  <div class="paper-inner">
    <h2>dinner:</h2>
    <p>Tuesday to Saturday 5.30 pm til 9.00 pm Bank Holiday Sundays 6pm til 9pm</p>
    <h2>lunch:</h2>
    <p>Friday 12.30 til 2.30 pm Sunday 12.30 til 4 pm</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `height: 100%;` не работает?

Comment: я щяс отправлю скрин что я хочу сделать

Comment: `height: inherit`

Comment: работает но margin не правильно тогда работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.paper {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.paper-inner {
  border: 1px solid #747474;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="paper">
  <div class="paper-inner">
    <h2>dinner:</h2>
    <p>Tuesday to Saturday 5.30 pm til 9.00 pm Bank Holiday Sundays 6pm til 9pm</p>
    <h2>lunch:</h2>
    <p>Friday 12.30 til 2.30 pm Sunday 12.30 til 4 pm</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое